# Single Container Pod yaml

Tags: kubernetes

Forgive my ignorance but I can't seem to find a way of using a yaml file to deploy a single container pod (read: `kind: Pod`). It appears the only way to do it is to use a deployment yaml file (read: `kind: Deployment`) with a replica of 1.

Is there really no way?

Why I ask is because it would be nice to put everything in source control, including the one off's like databases.

It would be awesome if there was a site with all the available options you can use in a yaml file (like vagrant's [vagrantfile](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/)). There isn't one, right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to find pod yaml files easily. For example, [the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/configuring-containers/#launching-a-container-using-a-configuration-file) has an example of a Pod being created.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:  # specification of the pod's contents
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - name: hello
    image: "ubuntu:14.04"
    command: ["/bin/echo", "hello", "world"]
```

One thing to note is that if a deployment or a replicaset created a resource on your behalf, there is no reason why you couldn't do the same.

`kubectl get pod <pod-name> -o yaml` should give you the YAML spec of a created pod.

There is [Kubernetes charts](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts), which serves as a repository for configuration surrounding complex applications, using the helm package manager. This would serve you well for deploying more complex applications.

Comment: Thank you for the tip on `-o yaml` of Kubernetes charts, that's very helpful!

Comment: When I run that I keep getting `STATUS` of `Completed` with `READY` of `0/1`. Even when I change the command to just `/bin/bash`, and when I delete the command entirely. Any idea how I can just get an ubuntu container to just sit there?

Comment: Invoke `sleep` with a large argument. There's also the pause container that does just that.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, figured it out. It's possible. You just use the multi-container yaml file (example found here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/pods/multi-container/) but only specify one container.

I'd tried it before but had inadvertently mistyped the yaml formatting.

Thanks rubber ducky!